# Capture screen of UBS-connected iPhone in macOS App

Tags: iphone, macos-sierra, screen-capture

**TL;DR: Can I capture an iPhone's screen from my macOS application?**

I've been searching for any APIs on macOS to to capture the screen of an iPhone that's connected to the computer, but haven't found any. Are there such public API's?

I've looked at SonOfGrab-example from apple, but that's only for processes running on the "current" computer from what I can figure out.

I want to do what QuickTime does when it records from the device, however I want to do it programmatically, by getting the image or a video stream of what's showing on the iPhone.